# Add fade-out transition to Bootstrap modal, that don't fall back to start point

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, transition, fadeout

basically, I want to do something pretty simple, but don't know how and haven't found a solution.

I got a modal, when I open it, it should move from left to the center.
On closing it, it should move to the right. (On default, it moves back to left.)

How can I add a extra transition for fade-out??

my less-code is this:

```
.modal {
  &.fade .modal-dialog {
    .translate(-25%, 0);
    .transition-transform(~"0.3s ease-out");
  }
  &.in .modal-dialog { .translate(0, 0) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for what I'm searching for. The Modal should move to the right-side on fade-out, but it still moves back to the left-side. Also, why gave me a negative for my question?